# Is it possible to override the name of ENUM for Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, enums

I have my enum as below

```
    enum class ImagesType(val descriptor: String) {
        BIGGER("Bigger Image - Fall"),
        SMALLER("Smaller Image - Lion"),
        TALLER("Taller Image - Tree"),
        LONGER("longer Image - Bridge")
    }
```

- When I `println(ImagesType.BIGGER)` it will print `BIGGER`
- When I `val x = ImagesType.valueOf("SMALLER")`, it will get `val x = SMALLER`

This is because the `name` is the same as the enum characters. I am hoping to override the `name` with the `description`, where the following will be true instead

- When I `println(ImagesType.BIGGER)` it will print `Bigger Image - Fall`
- When I `val x = ImagesType.valueOf("Smaller Image - Lion")`, it will get `val x = SMALLER`

I tried

```
    enum class ImagesType(override val name: String) {
        BIGGER("Bigger Image - Fall"),
        SMALLER("Smaller Image - Lion"),
        TALLER("Taller Image - Tree"),
        LONGER("longer Image - Bridge")
    }
```

But it fails stating that `name` is final.

Comment: just do `println(ImagesType.BIGGER.description)` and no, name can't be overridden as that is the actual name of the enum

Comment: You can do `override fun toString(): String = descriptor` to return the descriptor, instead. Then `println(ImagesType.BIGGER)` will do what you want. But I don't understand exactly what you want from the second line

Comment: I got to workaround as per my answer below. @mattfreake. Hopes that give a clearer picture of what I wanted to achieve. It's basically wanted the name to be something different from the Enum characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use way to get what I wanted.

```
    enum class ImagesType(val descriptor: String) {
        BIGGER("Bigger Image - Fall"),
        SMALLER("Smaller Image - Lion"),
        TALLER("Taller Image - Tree"),
        LONGER("longer Image - Bridge");

        override fun toString(): String {
            return descriptor
        }

        companion object {
            fun getEnum(value: String): ImagesType {
                return values().first { it.descriptor == value }
            }
        }
    }
```

So it get the result I need

- When I `println(ImagesType.BIGGER)` it will print `Bigger Image - Fall`
- When I val `x = ImagesType.getEnum("Smaller Image - Lion")`, it will get val `x = SMALLER`

I kind of workaround of overriding `valueOf` by replacing it with `getEnum`. Looks like `valueOf` can't be overriden.

Comment: I'd suggest renaming `getEnum()` to `forDescriptor()`, which has a clearer meaning when invoked as `ImagesType.forDescriptor()` and is more consistent with factory methods elsewhere.  Also, depending on how you're using it, it might read better to name the enum for the singular, not the plural (`ImageType`, not `ImagesType`).  Plus you can shorten the override to `override fun toString() = descriptor`.

Comment: Great answer. For longer enums, or just some unnecessary optimization, you can use a map for look-up by `descriptor`:

`private val descriptorLookup by lazy { values().associateBy { fp -> fp.descriptor } }`, and your fromDescriptor method simplifies to: `fun fromDescriptor(descriptor: String) = descriptorLookup[descriptor]
}`.